# Express Static Files - all route prefixes

Tags: node.js, express

In my code i currently have

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/../styles"))
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/../public"))
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/../scripts"))
app.use("/flosses", express.static(__dirname + "/../styles"))
app.use("/flosses", express.static(__dirname + "/../public"))
app.use("/flosses", express.static(__dirname + "/../scripts"))
app.use("/flosses/edit", express.static(__dirname + "/../styles"))
app.use("/flosses/edit", express.static(__dirname + "/../public"))
app.use("/flosses/edit", express.static(__dirname + "/../scripts"))
app.use("/accounts", express.static(__dirname + "/../styles"))
app.use("/accounts", express.static(__dirname + "/../public"))
app.use("/accounts", express.static(__dirname + "/../scripts"))
```

Which is very tedious. can I do something like this?

```
app.use("*",express.static(__dirname + "/../scripts"))
```

Note: I have my css,js and images in 3 different directories, and I need /thing1/index.css,/thing2/index.css,etc.

Thanks,

Ari

Comment: Why are you adding the static middleware to all of your routes? The first 3 lines should be enough.

Comment: @loganfsmyth: That Is The Only Way It Works

Comment: Are you configuring those static routes *before* or *after* your 'normal' (`app.get` and such) routes?

Comment: @robertklep with the rest of the middleware, _BEFORE_ the routes

Comment: @Ari so what happens if you use only the first three lines? Errors, other routes take precedence?

Comment: @robertklep: with only the first 3 lines `/things/index.css` results in a `404` error.

Comment: So for every prefix you need `/prefix/index.css` to work, *and* to have it point to the same `index.css` file on disk?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25917/discussion-between-ari-porad-and-robertklep)

Comment: @robertklep: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25917/discussion-between-ari-porad-and-robertklep)

Answer (score 1):

You could use this, which is a bit hacky IMO but it should work:

```
// place this after your routes
app.routes.get.forEach(function(r) {
  app.use(r.path, express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});
```

It only works for `GET` routes (hence the `app.routes.get`), and you might not need it for *every* route so you could filter on `r.path` to only pick out the routes you need). Also, I'm unsure about performance impact.

Comment: I can't get this to work, [here is a gist of my code](https://gist.github.com/porad/5129852)

Comment: That really looks scary, perhaps it's wiser if you augment your question to explain exactly what you have (in terms of files/directories) and what you're hoping to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just reference your statics at the root of your website, instead of adding them to every level of your application URIs?

That is what most people do, and what these frameworks are designed for.

Comment: wouldn't doing so expose your sever scripts to the public ?

Comment: You obviously wouldn't expose your src/ directory :), but you could map www.example.com, to actually go to /project/static on your webserver